# how to display circular progress in delphi ios apps?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

is there a easy way like in VCL (changing the cursor) to display the circular progress to say that something is going to de done ?

Comment: What? Do you mean like a spinning "loading in progress" thing?

Comment: @CaptJak Yes, it is what I need but I'm not familiar with Firemonkey

Comment: The word you are looking for is probably ["throbber"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber).

Answer (score 3):

In fact a component exist in FMX [TAniIndicator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/FMX.StdCtrls.TAniIndicator) and it is exactly what I need. Like shows the reference, the animated spinning indicator can be rendered e.g. as lines or as circles:

[image]

Comment: Don't you love those abbreviations. To a partially wordblind person like me, it looks like `TAnihilator` (: